# Why is sys_fork not used by glibc's implementation of fork?

Tags: c, linux, fork, glibc

In eglibc's `nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/fork.c` there's a definition:

```
#define ARCH_FORK() \
  INLINE_SYSCALL (clone, 5,                           \
          CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD, 0,     \
          NULL, NULL, &THREAD_SELF->tid)
```

which is used in actual `__libc_fork()` as the heart of the implementation. But e.g. in Linux's `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl` exists a `sys_fork` entry, as well as in `syscalls_64.tbl`. So apparently Linux does have its special syscall for `fork`.

So I now wonder: why does glibc implement `fork()` in terms of `clone`, if the kernel already provides the `fork` syscall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the commit where Ulrich Drepper added that code to glibc, and there wasn't any explanation in the commit log (or elsewhere).

Have a look at Linux's implementation of `fork`, though:

```
return _do_fork(SIGCHLD, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

And here is `clone`:

```
return _do_fork(clone_flags, newsp, 0, parent_tidptr, child_tidptr, tls);
```

Obviously, they are almost exactly the same. The only difference is that when calling `clone`, you can set various flags, can specify a stack size for the new process, etc. `fork` doesn't take any arguments.

Looking at Drepper's code, the `clone` flags are `CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD`. If `fork` was used, the only flag would be `SIGCHLD`.

Here is what the `clone` manpage says about those extra flags:

```
CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
          Erase child thread ID at location ctid in child memory when  the  child
          exits,  and  do  a  wakeup  on  the futex at that address.  The address
          involved may be changed by the set_tid_address(2) system call.  This is
          used by threading libraries.

CLONE_CHILD_SETTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
          Store child thread ID at location ctid in child memory.
```

...And you can see that he does pass a pointer to where the kernel should first store the child's thread ID and then later do a futex wakeup. Is glibc doing a futex wait on that address somewhere? I don't know. If so, that would explain why Drepper chose to use `clone`.

(And if not, it would be just one more example of the extreme accumulation of cruft which is our beloved glibc! If you wanted to find some nice, clean, well-maintained code, just keep moving and go have a look at musl libc!)

Comment: `pthread_join()` does the wakeup. Similar to how, if you link with threads, glibc calls `set_tid_address()` so the "main" thread can be joined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975098/when-is-the-system-call-set-tid-address-used

Comment: @usr: that new process can spawn threads. If you want those threads to be able to `pthread_join()` on the main thread of the new process, glibc needs the futex's address.

Comment: @usr: `execve()`takes care of that by calling `set_tid_address()`. BTW, if you immediately exec, there is `vfork()`, or `posix_spawn()`, if your libc provides that.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: why not?

You have one syscall that is guaranteed to exist on all platforms (you do realize that Intel isn't the only platform out there, right?), and another that is deprecated because it is unnecessary. They both carry the exact same semantics. Your code is much more compact when you only call the one guaranteed to exist.

I will elaborate on that a little.

Fork is defined by Posix, while clone is Linux specific. However, Linux, on occasion, takes Posix defined "system calls" and implements them in user space. Such is the case for fork (and vfork and pthread_create). They are all implemented in user space by calling "clone".

As such, fork is deemed unnecessary at the kernel level. If a thin user space wrapper can implement it, the kernel is okay with that. As such, **on Linux**, clone is guaranteed to exist on all platforms, while fork may or may not exist, depending on specific platform.

Comment: I believe `fork(2)` existed before `clone(2)`.

Comment: That is both correct and irrelevant. I've edited the answer to explain why.